# Determine getElementById length of input

Tags: javascript

I am using `if (document.getElementById('bedrijfsnaam').value == false)` to check if an input field has a value.
How to check if it has more then 5 characters?

Comment: `.value.length`

Comment: you need to put  validation.>

Comment: You can also use `if (document.getElementById('bedrijfsnaam').value && document.getElementById('bedrijfsnaam').value.length > 5)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple, just use `.length`:

```
if (document.getElementById('bedrijfsnaam').value.length > 5) {
  // do stuff
}
```

And here is the simple example with `.value.length`:

```js
var checkLength = function () {
  if (document.getElementById('bedrijfsnaam').value.length > 5) {
    document.getElementById('more').setAttribute('style', 'display: block');
    document.getElementById('less').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('more').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
    document.getElementById('less').setAttribute('style', 'display: block');
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="bedrijfsnaam" onkeyup="checkLength()">

<p id="more">Input value length is more then 5</p>
<p id="less">Input value length is less or equal to 5</p>
```

Comment: I have also updated the answer with a simple example

Comment: Can you change onkeypress event to onkeyup. onkeypress isn't fired for some keys like backspace/delete, whereas onkeyup is fired for all. The sequence of their execution is as: OnKeyDown > OnKeyPress > OnKeyUp. So onkeypress will be fired before the character occurs in the input box. So when the first character is typed, the length is actually 0 on keypress as the event is fired earlier whereas it should have been 1.

Comment: @SKSpall, it's a good suggestion, i have updated the answer with `onkeyup`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Say you are checking for both conditions together:

```
if (document.getElementById('bedrijfsnaam').value == false && document.getElementById('bedrijfsnaam').value.length>5)
```

**length** is a property of string that returns the number of characters in the string.

As *document.getElementById('bedrijfsnaam').value* will always return a string, you can easily calculate its length using this property.

Answer (score 0):

In javasscript if a string is empty it is evaluated as false and for length you can use its `length` property

```
var inp = document.getElementById('bedrijfsnaam').value;
if (inp && inp.length > 5){
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.getElementById("id").value.length > 5)
```

THIS IS THE BEST SOLUTION BUT : if you are using VSCODE be careful of the capital V in value added while typing.